# Debian 10 freezes, possibly related to running Zoom

Tags: debian, freeze

I have two computers (henceforth referred to as computer 1 and computer 2, respectively) on which I run Debian 10.

On computer 1, I have at two or three times had the computer seemingly freeze up, such that the screen would freeze and the computer would not respond to keyboard input (I was also unable to toggle keys like NumLock and CapsLock). On at least one of these occasions (possibly all, I don't quite remember), I have been running Zoom. The sound has then continued to work, both for myself and for the other participants in the call. In addition, the video from my camera has still worked for the other participants.

At first, I though there might be some kind of hardware issue with computer 1. However, I recently had the same problem occur on computer 2. Again, I was running Zoom. The computer seemingly froze and did not respond to keyboard input or mouse movement. However, the sound still worked and the video from my camera still worked for the other participants in the call.

There could of course be some kind of hardware issue with both computer 1 and computer 2. Howver, I am more inclined to believe it is software related, since I've had the same kind of issue on two different machines.

I am looking for advice on how to troubleshoot the error and suggestions for what might cause it.

**EDIT 1**

From the suggestions in the comments, I add the following information:

Item 1):

RAM is likely not an issue here. On computer 1, I have 16 GiB of RAM and 20 GiB of swap. On computer 2, I have 8 GiB of RAM and 16 GiB of swap.

Item 2):

As suggested by Artem S. Tashkinov, I checked `journalctl` and `dmesg` on computer 2. I'm not quite sure what to look for, but I did find at least one error message on computer 2 in `journalctl`, namely the following:

"kernel: usb 1-6: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84"

A similar message appears in `dmesg`. In `dmesg`, there are also some messages about the graphics driver (I think):

- [  321.794370] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load nouveau/nve7_fuc084 (-2)
- [  321.794377] firmware_class: See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for information about missing firmware
- [  321.794380] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nve7_fuc084 failed with error -2
- [  321.794395] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load nouveau/nve7_fuc084d (-2)
- [  321.794397] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nve7_fuc084d failed with error -2
- [  321.794399] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: unable to load firmware data
- [  321.794403] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: init failed, -19

Item 3):

I realize that I actually cannot boot computer 1 after the latest fail. When I try, the following happens:

*The system gets stuck at the following for a while: "fsckd-cancel-msg:Press Ctrl+C to cancel all filesystem checks in progress".

*After waiting for a while, I get some messages that seem related to my NVMe SSD, which I use for the system on computer 1:

- INFO: task fsck.ext4:492 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
- Not tainted 4.19.0-14-amd64 #1 Debian 4.19.171-2
- "3cho 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
- nvme nvme0: Device not ready: aborting reset

*After waiting a little more, I get a few error messages, with the following four repeated several times:

- Unmounting /boot/efi/...
- Deactivating swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/ (followed by a long string)
- [FAILED] unmounting /boot/efi
- [FAILED] Failed deactivating swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/ (followed by a long string)

*After that, nothing seems to happen.  I forcefully reboot the system by pressing Alt+SysReq+B. After rebooting, I don't reach the usual GRUB menu. Instead, the system gets stuck at the following:

"Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key".

Comment: My guess is that your RAM is being completely used, and the machine starts swapping. Can you monitor your RAM usage the next time this happens?

Comment: @terdon in an OOM situation mouse should continue working, so it might be a video driver crash of some sort. The OP: please check your `dmesg` or/and `journalctl` for anything unusual.

Comment: System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for your input! On computer 1 I have 16 GiB of RAM (and I believe 20 GiB of swap) and on computer 2 I have 8 GiB of RAM (and 16 GiB of swap). Hence, I don't think that lack of RAM is the issue.

Comment: @waltinator Thanks for your input! On computer 1 I have 16 GiB of RAM (and I believe 20 GiB of swap) and on computer 2 I have 8 GiB of RAM (and 16 GiB of swap). Hence, I don't think that lack of RAM is the

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: @waltinator Thanks for your the suggestion! I have added some more information to the question.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks for your input! I have added some information to my question.

Comment: `nouveau` is a reverse engineered NVIDIA GPU driver and in my experience it's prone to crashes. It would be great if you could try with proprietary NVIDIA drivers.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Yes, I guess I could try that. However, I don't know what to do about computer 1, since I cannot even boot it.